# L is a recognizable undecidable language ,M is a Turing machine that recognizes L, does M reject or infinitely loop for s belonging to L-complement?

Tags: turing-machines, decidability, turing-recognizable

If $L$ is a decidable language, $M$ is a Turing machine that determines $L$. For $\forall s \in L$, M accepts, and for $\forall s \in \overline{L}$, M rejects

However, my question is that
If $L$ is a recognizable undecidable language and $M$ is a Turing machine that recognizes $L$, for $\forall s \in L$, M accepts and for $\forall s \in \overline{L}$, M rejects or infinite loop? Or do both coexist, i.e., $\exists s \in \overline{L}$ and M rejects, and $\exists s \in \overline{L}$ and M infinitely loops?

Answer (score 1):

If $L$ is recognizable but not decidable, and $M$ is a Turing machine that recognizes $L$ then, for each $s \in \overline{L}$, $M(s)$ either rejects or it does not halt.

The behaviour of $M$ can differ for different choices of $s \in \overline{L}$, so it is definitely possible that there are $s_1, s_2 \in \overline{L}$ such that $M(s_1)$ halts and rejects, while $M(s_2)$ does not halt.